# Coordonates intervals as conditions give always false - Game, Kotlin, Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, coordinates, 2d-games

I am doing an android game from my university assignment but I do not know how to write in code a coordinates interval.
So, in the game, there is an obstacle that is going in the direction of the player (going from the top to the bottom of the screen) and the player has to avoid this obstacle. The problem is that, whenever the player touches the obstacle, I want the score to change and the obstacle to reset at the start (top of the screen).

For example:
If the obstacle coordinates are between the player zone (its position plus the length of the images), the obstacle gets a HIT = True, and so, the score is changed and the obstacle gets to the start position.

```
class Obstacle(){
   var x = Random.nextInt(0, 1080)*1f    //A place in the screen width
   var y = 0f                            //at the start position
   var speed = 20f
   var hit = false
   
   fun move(){
      hit = verifyHit(x,y)
      y += speed
      if (y>screen){
          y = 0
      }else if(hit){
         gameView.score --
         y=0
         hit = false
      }
   }

   fun verifyHit(x,y){
       return ((x > ufo.x || x < ufo.x + 400) || (y >= ufo.y || y < ufo.x + 400))
    }
```

The problem is that or this verifyHit return always false, or it returns always true. I have tried so many operators but this seems to be the more logical way to describe a zone on the screen. My last attempt was: the obstacle is only reached if it is in the intersection of the x interval and the y interval but when I run it, there is no effect so I conclude that it is always false.
Here it is a screenshot of my app screen:

[image]

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough info to determine why it's not giving you the correct result, but there are some design improvements you can make to have better separation of concerns, which will make it easier to track down the cause of this sort of bug.

Your Obstacle class shouldn't have to reference your player `ufo` instance directly. Having code like this makes it very difficult to maintain, because you start having various classes all pointing at each other, so when you change something about any class, it becomes difficult to find all the places you have to edit code to keep it working properly.

I would create an interface for bounds of an object and give it an intersects function to test when two objects overlap.

```
interface Rectangle {
    var x: Float
    var y: Float
    var width: Float = 0f // Default to point size
    var height: Float = 0f
}

infix fun Rectangle.intersects(o: Rectangle): Boolean {
    return x < r.x + r.width && x + width > r.x && y < r.y + r.height && y + height > r.y
}
```

Then you can make your Player and Obstacle classes implement this interface. Your player `ufo` instance can have a size of 400 or whatever defined in one place so other objects aren't having hard-coded numbers anywhere.

```
class Obstacle: Bounds {
   override var x = Random.nextInt(0, 1080).toFloat
   override var y = 0f
   override var speed = 20f
   
   fun move(){
      y += speed
      if (y > screen){
          y = 0
      }
   }

   fun reset() {
      y = 0
   }

}
```

It should be the responsibility of the owning class to work with the score and intersections between two objects Something like this:

```
for (obstacle in obstacles) {
    obstacle.move()
    if (obstacle intersects player) {
        gameScore--
        obstacle.reset()
    }
}
```